# Combine inline data with class data

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

I would like to ask if there's a way to combine `InlineData`with `ClassData` such as the following.

```
[Theory]
[TestData(inlineParam1, inlineParam2, ClassData(typeof(MyTestData)))] {
    // Do test
}
```

`TestData` is an invention of my own to resemble an attribute to be able to combine `InlineData` and `ClassData`.

Comment: Can you show the code where you're not combining the two as right now I don't even understand what you're trying to accomplish since even if we disregard the `ClassData` usage there the rest isn't legal C#.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking or what you are expecting as an answer. For any specific problem you are having please **include a [mcve]**. Please also read [ask] a good question.